# change img src on mouseover then change back on mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one larger image with two smaller thumbnails beneath it - Marked up as follows:

```
<img src="../images/image.jpg" class="left main" alt="main image" /> 
<img src="../images/image2-thumb.jpg" class="left mainthumb" alt="image two" /> 
<img src="../images/image3-thumb.jpg" class="left thumb mainthumb" alt="image three" />
```

I would like when image2-thumb or image3-thumb is hovered over for it to change image.jpg to the hovered images src BUT without the -thumb.

so if i hover over image2-thumb.jpg then image.jpg becomes image2.jpg and so on. Then on mouseout I would like it to revert back to its original src.

I'm using the following javascript to currently do this but on click:

```
$(function () {
    $('.mainthumb').click(function () {
        $('.main').attr('src', this.src.replace('-thumb', ''))
    });
});
```

I'd like to change this to hover but not sure how.

Comment: This is your previous question + the accepted answer.

Comment: dude, learn `javascript/jQuery` or else you'll just copy/paste code all the time... your last answer question just swaps click with mouseover

Answer (score 1):

Use [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
$(function () {
    $('.mainthumb').hover(function () {
        $('.main').prop('src', this.src.replace('-thumb', ''));
    }, function () {
        $('.main').prop('src', '../images/image.jpg');
    }
});
```

and Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Read [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to do this without jQuery using pure JS.

Something like this

```
<img src="first.png" onmouseover="this.src='second.jpg';"
        onmouseout="this.src='first-or-other-image.png'">
```

Maybe not very beautiful but works properly

Comment: Someone gave this a -1, but I think this is a working solution which is not off topic.

Comment: Works like a charm and is very simple - should be the accepted solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.mainthumb').mouseenter(function () {
    // Do your stuff.
});

$('.mainthumb').mouseleave(function () {
    // Do your stuff.    
});
```

Also see the [.hover() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with .hover() with callbacks

```
$('.mainthumb').hover(function () {
      // change the src        
}, function () {
      // change back the src 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the data attribute to the first image to store the original file pointer ("image.jpg") like this:

```
<img src="../images/image.jpg" data-original="../images/image.jpg" class="left main" alt="main image" />
```

And then add this to your javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('.mainthumb').hover(function () {
        $('.main').attr('src', this.src.replace('-thumb', ''))
    }, function() {
        var main = $('.main');
        main.attr('src', main.attr('data-original'));
    });
});
```